# Community♦ has two badges on Area 51

Tags: bug, area-51, community-user

The recent problem with the Community♦ user made me curious and I tried to see whether there were other oddities with that special user. Its reputation should be 1 everywhere and it shouldn't have any badge. However, it actually [has two badges](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) ([advocate](/questions/tagged/advocate) and [filibuster](/questions/tagged/filibuster)) on Area 51:

[image]

Is this a bug?

Comment: these badges were awarded back in 2011(-08-19).